# UIView layout a hierarchy

Tags: ios, uiview

Sorry for the newbie question, I'm still new and confused by UIKit.

I have a UIView A, with a subview B, which in turn has a subview C. All these are custom views, with layoutSubview and sizeThatFits implementations.

Now some UI event happens that should cause C to change its size ; concretely my controller will set a property on C. Because C will change sizes, that means B will have to be laid out again. That may cause it to change its own size, in which case A should be laid out again.
But I'm not sure who is responsible to call setNeedsLayout on A.

Should my property setter on C call [self.superview setNeedsLayout] ? If so, how does that message get propagated to A ? I don't think it makes sense to override setNeedsLayout in B so that it propagates the message upward.

Or should my controller call [A setNeedsLayout] ? But that doesn't feel right either. If the message does not cause B to resize, then A certainly doesn't need to be laid out, nor does it feel right for the controller to have to know the details of B and C interactions so it can decide whether A needs a layout.

How is this supposed to work if I want to implement it cleanly ?

Comment: 1. Why don't you try Autolayout? Delegate concept would be good here I think. Even if it is bit lengthy it's clean way.

Comment: It's beside the point – I'd like to understand how it's supposed to work, not give up and change technologies when I encounter the first small obstacle that should have a very simple answer. But for what it's worth, it's a very large app that is older than autolayout and none of the code is using it.

Comment: I would use delegate concept, so that C tells it's delegate(B) about size change and again B -> A